# Dictionary ключом которого является объект

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, имеется объект с переопределенным `GetHashCode`, который я хочу сделать ключом. `GetHashCode` вычисляется, как совокупность GetHashCode всех полей.

Я правильно понимаю, что HashCode вычисляется только 1 раз при добавлении в словарь?

Т.е. если в процессе жизни словарного объекта, одно из полей ключа поменяется, то при добавлении нового объекта в словарь с такими же полями, он не заметит дублей?

Судя по [исходникам](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,fd1acf96113fbda9) это так.

Получается, что для таких случаев нужно делать свою реализацию словаря или есть что-то готовое, что HashCode на ходу пересчитывает?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: мутабельный ключ не самая хороша я идея http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007296/c-sharp-dictionary-and-mutable-keys

Comment: Новые песни о главном... Обсуждали уже несколько раз. Читайте каноничные ответы по словарям и `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хэшкод объекта не должен меняться на протяжении жизни объекта. Эта рекомендация превращается в строгое правило, если объект служит ключом в `Dictionary<K, V>` или лежит в `HashSet<T>`.

Дело в том, что при поиске объекта в `Dictionary` сначала проверяется хэшкод, и на его основе определяется группа, в которой происходит дальнейший поиск. Если хэшкод меняется, объект может быть не найден.

Имеет смысл либо считать хэшкод только по неизменяемым полям, либо фиксировать хэшкод и запоминать его в поле объекта. Ну или просто гарантировать в коде, что пока объект в словаре, его хэшкод не меняется.

Хорошее дополнительное чтение по теме: [*Эрик Липперт*, Правила и рекомендации по переопределению `GetHashCode`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ruericlippert/2011/03/20/943/). И ещё: [MSDN: Remarks on `Object.GetHashCode` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) (особенно секция «Notes to Inheritors»).

---

Трюки с динамическим пересчётом хэшкода не смогут работать, т. к. в словаре объект попадает в ту или иную ячейку (bucket) хэш-таблицы в зависимости от своего хэшкода. Если разрешить смену хэшкода, то таблицу придётся перестраивать (перевычислять ячейки для ключей) при каждом обращении, а это означает катастрофическую просадку производительности.